# In 2D Array, if the index being used is 'None', it will result in all the values being changed? Why is that so?

Tags: python, numpy, multidimensional-array, nonetype

```
import numpy as np

board = np.zeros((3,3))
board[0][0] = 1
# This would result in the 0,0th entry being 1. 

board[None][0] = 2
# This would result in ALL entries being 2
```

Of course, I am aware that you should never supply the index as 'None', and I only stumbled upon this by accident.

But I cannot understand why using 'None' as an index would change all the values of a 2D array.
Should it not throw an error instead?

Using something similar on a 1D list threw an error for me.

Answer (score 1):

When working with Numpy arrays, indexing with `None` value is equivalent to [`numpy.newaxis`](https://numpy.org/devdocs/reference/constants.html#numpy.newaxis), which gets all the array values inside an specific dimension as you can see in the documentation:

```
import numpy as np

board = np.zeros((3,3))
print(board[None])
print(board[:, None])
```

**Output:** *Note that None indexing only works with NumPy arrays and tensor objects*

```
[[[0. 0. 0.]
  [0. 0. 0.]
  [0. 0. 0.]]]

[[[0. 0. 0.]]

 [[0. 0. 0.]]

 [[0. 0. 0.]]]
```